# Implementing filtered Iterator without using yield return

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop

I'm trying to display elements of a list with filter and without filter. Here, I use the filter in such a way to display the elements which are divisible by 3.  I'm going to use Enumerable and Enumerator interfaces to implement the list iterations. I was breaking my head to solve this but I end with empty hands, I'm sure about the logic and couldn't trace where I made mistake. So, I just place all of my code below.

In the FilterDisplay class, list is defined and a GetEnumerator() method is invoked and it's being used as

```
     public class FilterDisplay {
           public void TestIterators(){
          List<int> myList = new List<int> { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5 };
          for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
            Console.Write("{0} ", myList[i]);
          Console.WriteLine();

          IEnumerator<int> pi = myList.GetEnumerator();
          while (pi.MoveNext()){
            int x = pi.Current;
            Console.Write("{0} ", x);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();

          MyIntList myIntList = new MyIntList { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5 };
          IEnumerator<int> px = myIntList.GetEnumerator(x => 0 == x % 3);
          while ( px.MoveNext())
            Console.Write("{0} ", px.Current);
          Console.WriteLine();         // displays 3 9 6 3

          Console.ReadKey();
        }
      }
     }
```

MyIntList class implements list interface and GetEnumerator is defined and overridden within the class as;

```
public class MyIntList : IList<int>{
    public List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
    public MyIntList() {  }

    public void Add(int item) { MyList.Add(item); }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(){
        return new Enumerator1(MyList);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(Func<int, bool> filter){
        return new Enumerator1(filter, MyList);
    }
```

In the Enumerator1 class, I'm going to define the two constructors for implementing list and list with filter. Here, I'm trying to override MoveNext() and Current. When I tried to debug the project it shows error at Current. But, I'm sure there is no error in defining like that.

```
class Enumerator1 : IEnumerator<int>{
        private int i = -1;
        private MyIntList IntList;

        private Func<int, bool> NewFilter;
        private IEnumerator<int> NewMyList;

        public Enumerator1(IEnumerable<int> list){
            this.NewMyList = list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public Enumerator1(Func<int, bool> filter, IEnumerable<int> list){
            this.NewFilter = filter;
            this.NewMyList = list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool MoveNext(){
            i++;
            return i < IntList.MyList.Count;
        }

        public int Current { get { return IntList.MyList[i]; } }
        object IEnumerator<int>.Current { get { return NewMyList.Current; } }

        public void Dispose() { }
        public void Reset() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
```

I welcome any suggestions apart from using yield return, thanks.

Comment: Which `Current`? The explicitly implemented one likely behaves oddly (read: broken) since `MoveNext` doesn't mirror it.

Comment: object IEnumerator<int>.Current gives the error - explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface. @Telastyn

Comment: I didn't get your point MoveNext doesn't mirror it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use yield? And why are you not simply using Linq's Where(i => i % 3 == 0)?

Comment: What's the difference between this and [your earlier question](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250616/implementing-ienumerator-without-using-yield-return-in-c) ?

Comment: @giri - movenext and current work together. Movenext increments current so that stuff... Moves. With the explicit implementation it always uses the first element of the list, no matter how often MoveNext is called because MoveNext is working independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this (maybe because "yield return" breaks fix-and-continue in Visual Studio?), but if you're trying to create a filtered enumerator, here's one:

```
public class FilteredEnumerator<T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>
{
    readonly System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
    readonly System.Func<T, bool> filter; // could be null

    public FilteredEnumerator(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : this(enumerable, null) { }

    public FilteredEnumerator(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> enumerable, System.Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException();
        this.enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        this.filter = filter; // could be null for unconditional enumeration.
    }

    #region IEnumerator<T> Members

    public T Current { get { return enumerator.Current; } }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerator Members

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (filter == null || filter(enumerator.Current))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        enumerator.Reset();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I reflected the same. But the errors are not resolved. FilteredEnumerator<T> does not implement interface member IEnumerator.Current because it doesnot have the matching return type of 'object' and other one : 'IEnumerator<T>.Current' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface. 
@dbc

Comment: "FilteredEnumerator<T> does not implement interface member IEnumerator.Current" -- it's right here: `object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }`.  [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extends [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so it must be there to compile.  Did you try to compile and test the code before commenting?

Comment: Yes I did, the same error appears. I copied the errors in my above comment. @dbc

Comment: All I can think is that somehow you have redefined the meaning of IEnumerable<T>.  I modified the code to use fully qualified names so that there could be no confusion about namespaces.  Beyond that, it works for me, so good luck.